# How to string a value across two functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am new to the world of c# so go easy on me! :]

I am not even sure I am using the correct terminology. I figured this would be an easy google search but I am afraid I may not be wording this correctly.

I am gathering data from a database. Like so:

```
        SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strings.settings.connectionString);
        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT FNAME, LNAME, ZIPCODE FROM database WHERE ID = @ID";

        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtID.Text;
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

        if (mySqlDataReader.HasRows == false)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        if (mySqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            txtFname.Text = mySqlDataReader[0].ToString();
            txtLname.Text = mySqlDataReader[1].ToString();
            lblZipcode.Text = mySqlDataReader[2].ToString(); 
            //need help on stringing the value ZIPCODE above.  
        }
```

My question is: How can I string the Zipcode value to another function? I have been trying things like

```
 string Zipcode = mySqlDataReader[2].ToString();
```

but I get stuck trying to figure out how to string that value so I can use it in a different function like so:

```
 private void GetZipData()
 {
   //Get that value
 }
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but I think I lost the point. As far as I know 'string' is not a verb in english. What do you wanna do exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, Ill try and use my broken c# language to explain. I want to grab that mySqlDataReader[2] value and parse? the value to another function so I can use that value.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi. Actually it is a verb. In English. Example: "I am stringing those lights together."

Comment: @ShaiCohen True, but I'm not sure the use of "string" here makes sense.  At best, it's nonstandard usage in this context.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Thank you for mentioning that. But as Tim S already said, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understand that you wanna parse the zip code, but the question is to what? and what is the format of the zip code value?

Comment: I believe the OP may mean "pass" not "parse"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either I've misunderstood the question or your approach is fundamentally wrong. Firstly, your `GetZipData()` is returning `void` so is a subroutine, not a function. Even better, refer to it as a method as that covers both subs and funcs...

You can pass parameters in like this...

```
public void GetZipData(String SomeInputString) {
    ///Do something
}
```

and you can return things from a function like this...

```
public String GetZipData() {
    return "Some String";
}
```

What I suspect you want to do is get either a single Zip code or a list of zip codes from a data reader. Something like...

```
public String GetZipData(Integer Id) {
    //All your MySQL Code here
    return mySqlDataReader[2].ToString();
}
```

then you can simply call it like this...

```
String TheZipCode = GetZipData(123);
```

Of course, there are other things you can consider doing too - like creating a class to represent a customer and return that instead of a string - then you can get all the information in one Db trip...

```
class Person {
    String Firstname;
    String Lastname;
    String ZipCode;
}

public Person GetPersonData(Integer Id) {
    //All your MySQL Code here
    Person ReturnData = new Person();

    ReturnData.Firstname = mySqlDataReader[0].ToString();
    ReturnData.Lastname = mySqlDataReader[1].ToString();
    ReturnData.ZipCode = mySqlDataReader[2].ToString();

    return ReturnData;
}
```

Then you'd have...

```
Person person = GetPersonData(12);
//You can now use person.Firstname, person.ZipCode, etc...
```

Comment: Wow what a lesson! Thanks for clearing so many questions! Also thanks for the correction of my terminology. Would that mysqlDataReader[0] value be called a parameter? So I would say "I want to pass a parameter?" Or "pass a value"? This is really good info. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. A parameter is what you pass into a function. a "value" or "reference" can be returned. I think the word you're best sticking with for now is "variable" as it's more generic. There are 2 sorts of data type in .Net - Value types (Integer, Double, Structures, etc) and Reference types (String, Classes, etc). So, when using the word "value" make sure you're not accidentally confusing people :) Have a Google for more information on reference/value data types - they're important to know and it'll save you a lot of headaches later

Answer (score 2):

Change this method as

```
private string GetZipData()
 {
   string Zipcode = mySqlDataReader[2] as String;
   return Zipcode;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to pass the zip string to antoher method, you can add a string parameter to that method

```
private void DoSomethingWithZipCode(string zipCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine(zipCode);
}
```

If you want to return antoher value that depends on the zip code, you need a return type as well

```
private string GetCity(string zipCode)
{
    string city = <get city from database>;
    return city;
}
```

Or in your case

```
private string GetZipData(SqlDataReader dataReader)
{
    return dataReader[2].ToString(); 
}
```

You would call it like this

```
lblZipcode.Text = GetZipData(mySqlDataReader);
```

You can also write an extension method. You must place this method in a static class whose namespace is available where you are using it

```
public static string ZipData(this SqlDataReader dataReader)
{
    return dataReader[2].ToString(); 
}
```

You can call it like this

```
lblZipcode.Text = mySqlDataReader.ZipData();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string Zipcode = mySqlDataReader[2].ToString();

private void GetZipData(string yourInput)
{
   //do your stuff with yourInput
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your top data access code is in its own method you can 'return' it from there you would then call your data access method from the new value, see below:

```
return ZipCode

private void GetZipData() {
var stry=DataCode();
}
```

Regards
Craig